# How to replace a number of string with incremental count in python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I have some HTML code (for display in a browser) in a string which contains any number of svg images such as:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://localhost/images/Store.Tools.svg"></td>
    <td><img src="http://localhost/images/Store.Diapers.svg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to find all HTML links and replace them to the following (in order to attach them as email):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><cid:image1></td><td><cid:image2></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

SVG filenames can have any arbitrary number of dots, chars, and numbers.

What's the best way to do this in python?

Comment: You can use an HTML parser similar to [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: This is my code, I'm not scraping things.

Comment: BS is not limited to scraping anyway, it can be used for general HTML parsing as well.

Comment: Fair enough, I think it's more basic... the trick is incrementing image[#] every time a new "http" string is found. The reason it wasn't originally formatted well (thank you for those who helped format it nevertheless) is because it's all one line.

Comment: Check @alecxe's answer. That should do it. Doesn't matter really if it's one string. BS can parse it as long as it's well-formed. And even if it wasn't, there's a *chance* BS can fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use an HTML Parser to find all `img` tags and replace them.

Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and it's [`replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<table><tr>
<td><img src="http://localhost/images/Store.Tools.svg"></td>
<td><img src="http://localhost/images/Store.Diapers.svg"></td>
</tr></table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for index, image in enumerate(soup.find_all('img'), start=1):
    tag = soup.new_tag('img', src='cid:image{}'.format(index))
    image.replace_with(tag)

print soup.prettify()
```

Prints:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img src="cid:image1"/>
  </td>
  <td>
   <img src="cid:image2"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1: I knew you'd be working on it the moment I opened this post. :)

Comment: @Metatron thanks, opened the topic completely accidentally and unintentionally :)

Comment: Loving it! Followup: do I need to close w/ </cid>? I tested before w/o </cid> and it worked. Is there a way to tell replace_with not to make closing tags?

Comment: @Brongadier mm, would you be okay with having new elements self-closed, like `<cid:image1/>`?

Comment: @Brongadier okay, I've added some notes to the answer, please check.

Comment: @alecxe - found my issue, I forgot img tag, I need to replace it with: <img src="cid:image1"/>  -- thank you again!